# What are the differences between Elixir GenEvent's handle_call and handle_event?

Tags: elixir, gen-event

Please look at my answer below for the differences that I found and let me know if they are wrong or if there are more differences. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The difference that I saw on Elixir's [documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/GenEvent.html)

- `handle_call` must return a reply and `handle_event` does not have to return a reply

It seems to me that `event` is used to change the state and `call` is used to get the state.

Comment: `handle_event` can be synchronous by using `sync_notify`. The difference is  that `handle_call` will call one particular event handler in the event manager, `handle_event` will be called in all of them for every event.

Comment: So let's say I `notify` an event `{:custom_event, 1}`, every `handle_event` methods defined in the module will be called once? And if I make a `call`, only the `handle_call` for `{:custom_event, 1}` will be called?

Comment: No. A GenEvent is made of an event manager and many event handlers. You implement the handler in a module and you can add many handlers to a manager. So nofity will be call `handle_event` in all installed event handlers.